# my project in lamp not worked when i try to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, apache2

i recently installed lamp on ubuntu and now i got problems with them (i think that can not connected to database)

I did the following tests :

1. i tested mysql with call phpMyAdmin and that's done :

[phpMyAdmin screanShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcOH7.png)

2. i tested php with phpInfo and that's done too :

[phpInfo screanshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRxPO.png)

3. i tested simple code for to test the database connection

my simple code this is :

```
<?php
//phpinfo();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "3cret";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysql($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

And the result was:

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request. 500

Comment: 500 error means your PHP isn't executing *at all.*  Usually this means that mod_php isn't configured correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was due to disabled virtual Directory Support and that's solved with this command :

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Comment: why would you want to make all the files executable?

Answer (score 1):

There's either an error within your mod_php or your general PHP setup, I owuld also advise using mysqli over mysql as it is much better, use this code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","3cret","database_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: In `config/settings.inc.php`

Replace this line:

```
define('_PS_CACHE_ENABLED_', '1');
```

with this:

```
define('_PS_CACHE_ENABLED_', '0');
```

Enjoy!

Comment: where is this file located in Linux (Ubuntu) ? I didn't find this.